# MySQL multiple join returns incorrect value in SUM()

Tags: mysql

I want select order prices sum with multiple currencies.
When I use multiple joins, SUM() returns an incorrect number.

See query example:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(EUR.amount>0 AND EUR.stat="1", (EUR.amount), "0")) as EUR, SUM(IF(EUR.stat="3", (EUR.amount), "0")) EURPriceAdd, SUM(IF(EUR.amount>0 AND EUR.stat="1", (EUR.amount), "0")-IF(EUR.stat="2", (EUR.amount), "0")+IF(EUR.stat="3", (EUR.amount), "0")) as EURProfit, SUM(IF(USD.amount>0 AND USD.stat="1", (USD.amount), "0")) as USD, SUM(IF(USD.stat="3", (USD.amount), "0")) USDPriceAdd, SUM(IF(USD.amount>0 AND USD.stat="1", (USD.amount), "0")-IF(USD.stat="2", (USD.amount), "0")+IF(USD.stat="3", (USD.amount), "0")) as USDProfit, SUM(IF(USD.amount>0 AND USD.stat="1", (USD.amount), "0")-IF(USD.stat="2", (USD.amount), "0")+IF(USD.stat="3", (USD.amount), "0"))*3.1286937445402145
        +SUM(IF(EUR.amount>0 AND EUR.stat="1", (EUR.amount), "0")-IF(EUR.stat="2", (EUR.amount), "0")+IF(EUR.stat="3", (EUR.amount), "0"))*3.1286937445402145 AS totalaud, SUM(IF(orders.pay_status=3, IF(USD.amount>0 AND USD.stat="1", (USD.amount), "0")-IF(USD.stat="2", (USD.amount), "0")+IF(USD.stat="3", (USD.amount), "0"), "0"))*3.1286937445402145
        +SUM(IF(orders.pay_status=3, IF(EUR.amount>0 AND EUR.stat="1", (EUR.amount), "0")-IF(EUR.stat="2", (EUR.amount), "0")+IF(EUR.stat="3", (EUR.amount), "0"), "0"))*3.1286937445402145 AS totalpaid
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `orders_prices` AS `EUR` ON `EUR`.`currency` = 2 AND `EUR`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `orders_prices` AS `USD` ON `USD`.`currency` = 1 AND `USD`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `orders_prices` AS `AUD` ON `AUD`.`currency` = 3 AND `AUD`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
WHERE `orders`.`status` > 1
AND `orders`.`status` < 8
AND `orders`.`user` = '17'
AND DATE(orders.converted_at) >= '2021-07-01'
AND DATE(orders.converted_at) <= '2021-08-02'
```

If I delete the join AUD then the query works properly.

How I can use multiple join and calculate exact numbers.

This is example of orders_prices
[image]

Comment: Hi @LEVANCHIKA for both AUD & USD will currency be same?

Comment: No, it looks like a mistake was made. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @LEVANCHIKA! Please provide sample data and expected result if possible.

Comment: This is data without AUD join:

` [EUR] => 0
    [EURPriceAdd] => 0
    [EURProfit] => 0
    [USD] => 1150
    [USDPriceAdd] => 0
    [USDProfit] => 200
    [totalaud] => 624.8799800872803
    [totalpaid] => 0`

And this is with AUD join:

``` [EUR] => 0
    [EURPriceAdd] => 0
    [EURProfit] => 0
    [USD] => 4600
    [USDPriceAdd] => 0
    [USDProfit] => 800
    [totalaud] => 2499.519920349121
    [totalpaid] => 0`